# NodeJS + JS: generating dynamic links, depending on current user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, hyperlink, dynamic-data

I'm trying to create a simple sorting option for posts in my blog. The problem is the last thing I want to use is a JS-based redirections because of the fact some users don't have JS enabled in their browsers, thats why they wont be able to sort posts in me blog. Let me give you an example:

I have several categories in my blog:

```
//categories selection
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a id="cat1" href="/?category=music">Music</a></li>
    <li><a id="cat2" href="/?category=photo">Photo</a></li>
    <li><a id="cat3" href="/?category=cinema">Cinema</a></li>
    <li><a id="cat4" href="/?category=computers">Computes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, I have two sorting options:

```
//sorting options
<div>
    <a class="active">Last posts</a>
    <a>Last comments</a>
</div>
```

Depening on current active elements, user is redirected on page with such parameters, e.g. '/?category=music&sort=posted' or '/?category=personal&sort=commented'.

For example, lets take that in categories selection 'CINEMA' tab is active at this moment (

```
<li class="actvie"><a id="cat3" href="/?category=cinema">Cinema</a></li>
```

). So, if user clicks Last comments link, it should redirect to

```
'/?category=cinema&sort=comments'
```

Another example: currently Last comments is active (

```
<a class="active">Last comments</a>
```

). User clicks on Computes in category selection and it should redirect to

```
'/?category=computers&sort=comments'.
```

So, are there any variants for performing such feature without JS? If no, could you suggest me the most elegant solution except manually running over every element in category and sorting optiona and generation link with JS/jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

**SERVER SIDE:**

```
db.collection("posts", function (err, collection) {
    //getting posts dependinc on requested category
    collection.find({category: req.query['category']}, {sort: [['time_added', -1]], limit:20}, function (err, posts) {
        //getting posts and rendering page
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**: I've found a so-so solution. For a separate category I render two div's with different posts list. One for 'Last posted', the second - for 'Last commented'. And the sort selector will just hide one div and shows another. The problem is just twice data size transfering to client side. I know, it will require a bit JS, but the main category links would be clear without '#'-hrefs. And sort options - it's just a toogle, it may not have real link.

Comment: If you decide to do it like that you can actually use a CSS only solution instead of Javascript to toggle between the two. Have a look at the :focus, :active or :target selector in CSS. Here's an example http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target#item2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are doing a page refresh for selecting a new category. Use the selected category parameter to determine the URL of the sorting options. Would need some more code from your server side to give you a more concrete example.

If you don't want to use Javascript you will have to generate the href-attribute of your sorting links `<a class="active">Last posts</a>` dynamically based on which category is selected. How are you rendering the page today? Just static files? Have a look at a template engine like mustache.js and then you could do it like this:

```
<a class="active" href="/?category={{category}}&sort=comments">Last posts</a>
```

Have a look at this tutorial for an Node.js example using mustache.js
http://mrjaba.posterous.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-nodejs

Edited after your comment: Or something like this using EJS

```
<div>
    <a href="/?category=<%=category%>&sort=posts" class="active">Last posts</a>
    <a href="/?category=<%=category%>&sort=comments">Last comments</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Well. i've updated my post. However there'a absolutely no any special tricks there. I just parse 'category' and 'sort' parameters and depending on it I render the page with requested posts. Please, take in account I've not yet still completed sort options on backbends, that why I don't include it into my code.

Comment: If you don't want to use Javascript you will have to generate the href-attribute of your sorting links <a class="active">Last posts</a> dynamically based on which category is selected. How are you rendering the page today? Just static files? Have a look at a template engine like mustache.js and then you could do it like this: <a class="active" href="/?category={{category}}&sort=comments">Last posts</a>

Comment: If fact I'm quite familliar with EJS Template engine. The problem is during the rendering process I have to render "hard" links for categories, and after user changes the 'sort' option, categories link should be modified. I don't know how to do it without JS.

Comment: I've found a so-so solution. Please, take a look at the updated post.

Comment: I saw your solution. You don't have to render two different divs though. Instead of doing a conditional with EJS you could just inject the value into the href attribute: <a class="active" href="/?category=<%=category%>&sort=comments">Last posts</a>

Comment: Well, I suppose there a kind of misunderstanding) Lets imagine a such situation: user requested /?category=music&sort=posted. We render page, where categories list have hrefs like /?category=music&sort=posted. Then user changes sort toogle to 'commented'. Category hrefs should link to /?category=music&sort=commented as user changed prefered sorting way.

Comment: Yeah. That's why you use <%=category%> inside the A href attribute instead of hard coding it. <a href="/?category=<%=category%>&sort=posts"> will be different things depending on which category the user has selected. Because you are doing a page refresh when the category is changed, right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about doing the actual sorting on the client side or the server side? If the latter, there's no problem; just stick with the URLs you have and have the server rewrite them and redirect to the new ones (if you even have to do that; you could just treat the "shorter" URLs as the actual ones for the sorted content). This is no way relies on client-side scripting being available.

You can, of course, implement client-side sorting *on top of this* as a convenience for users who do have client-side scripting available; the key here is to use unobtrusive JavaScript (e.g. install handlers at load time to intercept clicks on the sorting links).